# Disabling GreenAddress 2FA ∵ Google Authenticator doesn't generate the correct OTPs for it

Tags: authentication, two-factor, green-address, greenbits, two-factor-authentication

According to the section "I lost my two-factor/mobile/etc (email/OTP|Authenticator/etc), what can I do?" of the [GreenAddress FAQ page](https://greenaddress.it/it/faq.html),

> You should always have at least two two-factor options enabled.

Unfortunately, I did not. I only kept the Google Authenticator one enabled.

> Additionally for OTP/Authenticator you should back up the initial seed number and/or QR code displayed. Provided you keep these backups you can maintain access to your coins even if you lose access to one method for any reason.

I did keep a backup of the Google Authenticator QR code (is this the same as the "initial seed number"?), but when I use the Google Authenticator or Authy apps to generate a OTP, GreenAddress / GreenBits doesn't recognize it.

Why would this be?

Is there a way to disable GreenAdress 2FA using the mnemonic and/or PIN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can think of that would result in the above with a valid OTP seed is invalid OTP settings (but default should work for Google Auth) OR incorrect time on the device OR invalid time (drifted) on the GreenAddress service clock.

I checked for the last one personally and the services clock is fine: in my experience most of the time is time/synchronization on the device.

There is no way of disabling GreenAddress 2FA without 2FA however users that created 2of3 subaccounts can use their two keys to spend/recover and users that enabled email notification with nlocktime can bypass the 2FA after a period of time (by default 90 days, min 1 day, or maximum nlocktime allows)

Thanks

Comment: There's a way to fiddle with the Google Auth OTP settings?

Comment: When you add a key manually it allows for time or counter based. I think with qrcode it doesn't ask and defaults